# Add date field to imported csv file

Tags: arcpy, csv, feature-class

I am using a script written by [John](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/54686/john) to import a csv file and make a point feature class. My table looks like this:

```
"timestamp_pretty","mmsi","imo","shipType","lat","long","month","week"
"31/12/1969 23:59:59",265650950,9544322,"HSC",57.661503,11.84175,12,1
"31/12/1969 23:59:59",305706000,9583902,"CARGO",59.486267,20.078266,12,1
```

Tthere is a date field in my table. How to import it as date format instead of text?

```
# Author: John K. Tran
# Contact: jtran20@masonlive.gmu.edu

import arcpy
import os
import csv
import time
import locale
from arcpy import env

start_time = time.time()

##incsv = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
##outfc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

incsv = r"E:\DensityMaps\TestFilesLoop\test.csv" # Change this to the path of your CSV file.
outfc = r"E:\DensityMaps\DensityMapsTest1.gdb\TestSampleFC" # Change this to the path of your output FC.

spatialref = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326) # Create the spatial reference object as WGS84. Can modify if desired.

if not arcpy.Exists(outfc): # Create the output feature class if needed.
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.dirname(outfc), os.path.basename(outfc), "POINT", None, None, None, spatialref)

csv.register_dialect("xls", delimiter=",", lineterminator="\n") # Register the dialect for native CSV syntax in Microsoft Excel.
f = open(incsv, "r")
reader = csv.reader(f, dialect = "xls")

headers = reader.next() # Read the first line as the header names.
headerDate = headers.index("timestamp_pretty")

for header in headers[0:]: # Add fields for remaining columns if needed. Default is TEXT field.
    arcpy.AddField_management(outfc, header , "TEXT")

    print "Header: "+header

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outfc, ['SHAPE@XY'] + headers[0:]) # Create InsertCursor.
count = 0
for row in reader:
    if count % 1000 == 0:
        print "processing row {0}".format(count)

    date = row[0]
    Ycoord = row[4] # Make sure 'Lat' is in the 4th column.
    Xcoord = row[5] # Make sure 'Lon' is in the 5th column.
    newrow = [(float(Xcoord), float(Ycoord))] + row[0:]
    cursor.insertRow(newrow) # Insert point in FC for each row in CSV.
    count += 1

del cursor
f.close()
print ("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you were adding all fields as "TEXT".  The first one should have been a date.  Here is an example where you can map the field types with the headers:

```
import arcpy
import os
import csv
import time
import locale
from arcpy import env

start_time = time.time()

##incsv = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
##outfc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

incsv = r"E:\DensityMaps\TestFilesLoop\test.csv" # Change this to the path of your CSV file.
outfc = r"E:\DensityMaps\DensityMapsTest1.gdb\TestSampleFC" # Change this to the path of your output FC.

spatialref = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326) # Create the spatial reference object as WGS84. Can modify if desired.

if not arcpy.Exists(outfc): # Create the output feature class if needed.
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.dirname(outfc), os.path.basename(outfc), "POINT", None, None, None, spatialref)

csv.register_dialect("xls", delimiter=",", lineterminator="\n") # Register the dialect for native CSV syntax in Microsoft Excel.
f = open(incsv, "r")
reader = csv.reader(f, dialect = "xls")

headers = reader.next() # Read the first line as the header names.

headerDate = headers.index("timestamp_pretty")

# do the 2nd and 3rd field need to be long?
for header,ftype in zip(headers, ['DATE','TEXT','TEXT','TEXT','DOUBLE','DOUBLE','SHORT','SHORT']):
    arcpy.AddField_management(outfc, header , ftype)

    print "Header: "+header

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outfc, ['SHAPE@XY'] + headers[0:]) # Create InsertCursor.
count = 0
for row in reader:
    if count % 1000 == 0:
        print "processing row {0}".format(count)

    date = row[0]
    Ycoord = row[4] # Make sure 'Lat' is in the 4th column.
    Xcoord = row[5] # Make sure 'Lon' is in the 5th column.
    newrow = [(float(Xcoord), float(Ycoord))] + row[0:]
    cursor.insertRow(newrow) # Insert point in FC for each row in CSV.
    count += 1

del cursor
f.close()
print ("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

EDIT:

Here is a pic of the output table.

[image]

Comment: will the date field get populated properly? I suppose we need to change text field content to a datetime e.g. datetime.datetime.strptime(a_date, date_fmt)

Comment: Yep, I ran this script and it was formatted correctly in the output feature class.  I see now why you would ask that, since it starts with `31/12`, but apparently ArcGIS is smart enough to reformat it.

Comment: I added a picture of the output table so you can see that the date was indeed populated correctly.